# миллисекунды в минуты, часы, дни, года и т.д

Tags: java

Есть определенная переменная, которая хранит в себе количество миллисекунд.

Есть строка, в которой может быть `Y` - год (не високосный), `M` - месяц (30 дней), `w` - неделя, `d` - день, `h` - час, `m` - минута, `s` - секунда, `S` - миллисекунда.

Строка может быть, например, формата `"Y-d-m"`. Такая строка должна вернуть вместо букв числа:

- количество лет,
- количество дней, которых не хватило до 1 года,
- количество минут, которых не хватило до 1 дня.

Или `"Y-M-d-h-s"` должен вернуть:

- кол-во лет,
- кол-во месяцев, которых не хватило до 1 года,
- количество дней, которых не хватило до 1 месяца,
- количество часов, не хвативших до 1 дня,
- количество секунд, не хвативших до часа.

Ну и все в таком духе.

Можно ли такое сделать с применение какого-либо встроенного или уже готового класса или мне нужно иди самому писать такую штуку?

Comment: класс java.util.Date имеет все необходимые инструменты для работы с датой. Класс Instant  поможет  со временем, включая секунды

Comment: Vladik, я такого не говорил. Там отдельно кол-во лет и кол-во месяцев

Comment: Труфальдино, а разве Date не вернет, 1 год и 1 день, если я не укажу месяц в формате даты, а времени, например будет на 1 год и 31 день (считаю месяц за 30 дней)

Comment: Вам придется самому написать такую штуку, есть только встроенная реализация работы с реальным календарём. Из хороших новостей, это легко решается банальными операциями деления и взятия остатков от деления - плавающие данные убраны в виде високосных годов и разных количествах дней в месяцах. Сделать split на маске по `-` и загнать в цикл со switch тоже не проблема.

Comment: Единственное будьте внимательны, поскольку в задаче у вас "кол-во, которого не хватило до полного числа". То есть по задаче, если у вас прошло 12 лет и 3 месяца, то вернуть в `M` вы должны 9 месяцев. И еще я вижу, что в реализации идет просмотр до чего не хватило - в первом варианте дней до года, а во втором дней до месяца. То есть в каждом case логика будет с просмотром предыдущего значения, которое вычислялось и отчет до него.

Comment: _Какое_ количество миллисекунд?  От какого момента и в каком году:  1 января в 1970, 1900 или может в 1912 году?

Comment: Возможно, речь не про момент времени, а про длительность. @Труфальдино, уточните в формулировке вопроса, что у вас хранится в миллисекундах: момент времени начиная с какого-то года или длительность (период) без привязки к определенному моменту времени?

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn,Все что  нужно, есть в пакетах java.util и java.time.  Для решения задачи можно восползоваться замечательным классом Duration и егостатическими методами: plus.minus,  plus nanons,minus  nanos, plusdays, minusdays и прачая. Если совсем лениво, то Кей Хорстман  второе  издание "Java SE 9. Базовый Курс",страница  460-463

Answer (score 1):

Пусть у вас есть класс с константами, которые показывают количество миллисекунд в секунде, минуте и так далее. И соответствие символов паттерна с количеством миллисекунд:

```java
class Constants {
    static final long SECOND = 1000;
    static final long MINUTE = SECOND * 60;
    static final long HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
    static final long DAY = HOUR * 24;
    static final long MONTH = DAY * 30;
    static final long YEAR = DAY * 365;
    static final Map<Character, Long> MAP = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        MAP.put('s', SECOND);
        MAP.put('m', MINUTE);
        MAP.put('h', HOUR);
        MAP.put('d', DAY);
        MAP.put('M', MONTH);
        MAP.put('Y', YEAR);
    }
}
```

Например, чтобы реализовать форматирование по паттерну `Y-d-m`, можно написать следующий код:

```java
long millis = 31622460000L;
long Y = millis / YEAR;
long d = millis % YEAR / DAY;
long m = millis % YEAR % DAY / MINUTE;
String.format("%d-%d-%d", Y, d, m); // => "1-1-1"
```

А чтобы реализовать форматирование по паттерну `Y-M-d-h-s`, получается следующее:

```java
long millis = 34218001000L;
long Y = millis / YEAR;
long M = millis % YEAR / MONTH;
long d = millis % YEAR % MONTH / DAY;
long h = millis % YEAR % MONTH % DAY / HOUR;
long s = millis % YEAR % MONTH % DAY % HOUR / SECOND;
String.format("%d-%d-%d-%d-%d", Y, M, d, h, s); // => "1-1-1-1-1"
```

Обобщая код выше, можно написать статический метод `format`, который будет форматировать по произвольному паттерну:

```java
static String format(String pattern, long millis) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    long remainder = millis;
    for (char p : pattern.toCharArray()) {
        if (p == '-') continue;
        long value = MAP.get(p);
        output.append('-');
        output.append(remainder / value);
        remainder %= value;
    }
    return output.substring(1);
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```java
format("Y-d-m", 31622460000L); // => "1-1-1"
format("Y-M-d-h-s", 34218001000L); // => "1-1-1-1-1"
```

Для краткости в моей реализации пропущены недели и миллисекунды. При необходимости их можно добавить в класс с константами.